# How display double quotation to input via javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I have observable model, I initialized in javascript:

```
var name = '@(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.Name))';
```

The Model.Name = `"123"`

But it render like `var name = '\&quot;123\&quot;';`

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var name = '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.Name))';`

This will always be correctly encoded and it won't be vulnerable to [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) if `Model.Name` ever ends up being user controlled.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var name = '@Html.Raw(Model.Name)';
```

Comment: If I use RAW `&` converted to '&amp;'

Comment: What & is converted? If Model.Name = "123", then you should have var name = '123';

Comment: With `Model.Name = "first&second"`, `var name = '@Html.Raw(Model.Name)';` renders `var name = 'first&second';`

Comment: This could be vulnerable to XSS (depending on the source of your variable of course) so it is bad practise not to correctly encode it. Please see my answer.

Comment: Yes, of course, I assumed that the Model contains a safe value.

Comment: Model.Name = `'"123"'`

Answer (score -1):

Use double double-quotes like this `""123""`